# Hazelcast AWS EC2 Autodiscovery not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast-all-3.5.4.jar in my project.
I tried to run two instance of my application in one EC2 instance and two are joining the cluster with `<aws enabled="true">`.

I created another EC2 instance (using AMI option, same settings). When i run the same application as in the other node, the new node is not joining the cluster.

The INFO message  Could not connect to: <ipaddress>. Reason: SocketException[Connection timed out to address is getting printed though.

It is finding the other node though 
     Connecting to <ipaddress>, timeout: 0, bind-any: true

Following messages are also displayed

```
INFO <ipaddress>  Creating AWSJoiner
com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoinerOverAWS
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketConnector
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I enabled all the TCP ports in security group inbound traffic and it is working now.

Comment: I just started working on the Hazelcast AWS configuration. Could you please share the configuration for AWS Hazelcast?